# User Presence on Documents in Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm relatively new to Firestore.

**Question**

I need to create a presence system in an Angular application that reflects a user's viewing state on a Firestore document, basically like ye olde Google Sheets/Docs does. What would be the most effective/efficient way to implement this in Firestore?

**Current solution**

My current solution is to `doc.update()` an array of currently viewing user IDs whenever the view renders and destroys. Manually handling presence feels like asking for trouble, correct me if I'm wrong.

**Context (simplified)**

In the application, after authentication, users can read and write documents using a singular document view. (e.g. a table display at /table/{uid})

The document view reflects changes in the document in real time, so multiple users can read/write the document concurrently if they have the unique link.

I understand the solution presented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

However, I am not (directly) interested in a user's global activity state per se. I only need to know whether a  given user is currently viewing the document or not, so I can present that state back to other users in the document's view.

Comment: Cloud Firestore doesn't provide a way to know what a user is currently doing in the database, and it also doesn't account for the fact that a user can simply disappear any moment without notice.  I think you'll need to use a combination of the presence solution you linked, with a combination of some activity tracking code that you write.

Comment: While this is a valid question, I am going to mark this as a duplicate because the info you need to craft a presence system *for* Firestore has been discussed and there are several other SO questions about it along with a guide on how to do it. It's not specific to angular but the concepts are there. With the info presented in the link, you can determine if a user is viewing a document by flagging it (in a number of ways) as being read, and if the user d/c's reset the flag.